# jQuery, AJAX and Codeigniter - form submit does not work

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to all this AJAX thing so I thought that good learning will be to build simple TODO list. Below is index.php and corresponding controller. Index gets loaded without errors, but when I submit my task nothing is happening. Only page gets reloaded. Database is still empty.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Todo</h1>
<form id="add" >
    <input type="input" name="task" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" /><br />
</form>
<script>

$("form").submit(function() {
    var value = $("input:first").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>todo/add/" + $("input:first").val(),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function()
        {
            var newP = $('<p />').text(value);
            $(".todos").append(newP).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
    return true;
});

</script>
<div class="todos"></div>
<p>Załadowano w <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong></p>
</body>
```

controller/todo.php

```
<?php
class Todo extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('todo_model');
    }

    public function index($type = NULL)
    {
        $this->load->view('todo/index');
    }

    public function add($data)
    {
        $this->Todo_model->add($this->input->xss_clean($data));
    }
}
?>
```

Update:
todo_model.php:

```
  <?php
  class Todo_model extends CI_Model {

      public function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->database();
      }

      public function add($data)
      {
          $this->db->insert('todo', $data);
      }

      public function get()
      {
          return $this->db->get('todo')->result();
      }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Does the insert work if you just visit the page with your browser (or cURL)?

Comment: Yes, add function works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
public function add($data)
    {
        $this->Todo_model->add($data);
    }
```

instead of:

```
public function add($data)
    {
        $this->Todo_model->add($this->input->xss_clean($data));
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>todo/add/',
data: 'data=' + $("input:first").val(),
success: function(resp) {
             //rest processing
         }
});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function add()
    {
        $this->Todo_model->add($this->input->post('data'));
    }
```

Comment: Made your changes. Did a little debuging with print_r and die(). Add function isn't loading.

Comment: try after adding index.php in your url

Comment: No, `type:'POST'` is correct. It is not `method:'POST'`. If the problem is with the `add()` method in the model, show us that code.

Comment: Got some errors from PHP, [Tue Mar 13 19:38:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function add() on a non-object in /home/stamp/public_html/test/application/controllers/todo.php on line 17, referer: http://127.0.0.1/dev/test/index.php/todo/index

Answer (score 0):

- You'll need to use a debugger like Firebug console to see what the reply of the server is to your request.
- In your script section

> `$(function(){}`

is missing, which should be wrapped around your jQuery

- use something like this to stop the form from submitting:

> ```
> if (evt.preventDefault()) {
> evt.preventDefault();
> }else{
> evt.returnValue = false;
> }
> ```

Comment: How to check replay in firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one then debug with firebug by clicking on firebug icon then clicking on Console to see what you submit and how the response is

var id = 1;

$.ajax({

```
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>todo/add/",
    data: {id : id},
    success: function()
    {
        var newP = $('<p />').text(value);
        $(".todos").append(newP).fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```